# Hook not firing for custom entity -- how to set theme suggestions?

Tags: 8, theming

I have an entity whose machine name is orb_act.  This code is not firing in Drupal 8:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter().
 */
function mytheme_theme_suggestions_orb_act_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) {

  // Add template suggestions based on the current view mode.

  $suggestions[] = 'orb_act';
  $suggestions[] = 'orb_act__' . $variables['elements']['#view_mode'];

}
```

How do I set my template suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The theme system doesn't know about entity types by default. You need to implement hook_theme() yourself at the moment. You likely also need a preprocess function to define a few standard things.

The console project generates this when creating a new entity type through it, you could try that to see how it looks. Otherwise look at what node module does in node_theme() and template_preprocess_node().

Comment: Berdir, I generated the entity module through console, and have looked at the node module, but still don't see how to add template suggestions per view mode.  Still looking :)

Comment: Though I've generated my module with console, none of the relevant hooks seem to be firing.  This fires: hook_theme_suggestions_alter().  But not this:  hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter().  There don't appear to be any hooks that are specific to my entity type.

Comment: Berdir, I got it working, and your answer is essentially correct.  It came down to using keys in hook_theme that match my template names.  Underscores in the keys are also underscores in the file names.  /**
 * Implements hook_theme().
 */
function my_module_theme() {
  return [
    'my_entity' => [
      'render element' => 'elements',
      'template' => 'my_entity',
    ],
  ];
} -- See also:  https://www.drupal.org/project/eck/issues/1321412#comment-5162124